# Find usage of a function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to find a usage of a function in SQL server 2008?

Answer (score 16):

The answer for SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sc.id, 
                so.name 
FROM   syscomments sc 
       INNER JOIN sysobjects so 
         ON so.id = sc.id 
WHERE  sc.TEXT LIKE '%functionname%' 
ORDER  BY 2
```

[image]

Comment: Per @gbn, You can't use sys.comments because the type is nvarchar(4000)

Comment: Have you tested it before down voting? I just tested it, syscomments definitely works.

Comment: Yes. if the text you are looking for is beyond the first 4000 characters, it would not be found in the search.

Answer (score 14):

Use in code:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%MyFunc%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM sys.computed_columns WHERE definition LIKE '%MyFunc%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints WHERE definition LIKE '%MyFunc%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM sys.default_constraints WHERE definition LIKE '%MyFunc%'
```

I think I've covered all bases...

You can't use sys.comments because the type is nvarchar(4000)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it really cover everying (table, function, procedures and triggers)?

Comment: To avoid `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`, replace the `*` with `CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), N'.', OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS SchemaObjectName`

Answer (score 1):

With SQL2012, use sp_depends in your database will list all usage inside.

ex.

- EXEC sp_depends 'FunctionNameToSearch'
- EXEC sp_depends 'TableNameToSearch'
- EXEC sp_depends 'StoredProcNameToSearch'

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that by "usage" you mean "usage statistics", then maybe [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) is useful for you.